# Post request is pending and then failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, axios

My endpoint:

```
app.post("/createCar", async (req, res) => {
    const car = req.body;
    const newCar = new CarModel(car);

    try {
        await newCar.save();

        res.json(car);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ msg: error })
    }

});
```

My axios request:

```
const createCar = () => {
    Axios.post('http://locahost:3001/createCar', { company: company, model: model, year: year, power: power, price: price }).then((response) => {
      setAllCars([{ company: company, model: model, year: year, power: power, price: price }, ...allCars])
    })
  }
```

And I use this function here:

```
 <button type="button" onClick={createCar}>Submit</button>
```

So when I click the button I see this:

[createCar request(pending)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptM44.png)

And then this:
[createCar request(failed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvLgz.png)

But there is data from my inputs:
[payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPwel.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcPh6.png)

Comment: You can try await CarModel.create({company:req.body.company, model:req.body.model, year:req.body.year, power:req.body.power, price:req.body.price});

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatly it doesn`t work :(